# How to build from a single codebase a web and a desktop applications?

Tags: javascript

I comes into applications like [linear.app](https://linear.app/) and [height.app](https://height.app). They both have a web application run in a browser and a desktop application run in your system, and they look similar. I believe they must be built from a common codebase. Do anyone know what tech stacks they are using?

Comment: Electron, maybe

Comment: linear.com is build with PWA. Creating PWA is relatively easier than Electron or other. There are lots of packages out there to create pwa application. i.e. NextJs - next-pwa